# Can't locate element with selenium webdriver on python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want python with selenium webdriver to do the following:-

1. Open Facebook
2. Login
3. Click and open the user pane which has the "Logout" option

A small arrow opens the user pane

I wrote the following script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
def open_url(url):
    driver.get(url)
    assert "Facebook" in driver.title
def login(user_id,user_pass):
    elem_id=driver.find_element_by_name("email")
    elem_id.clear()
    elem_id.send_keys(user_id)
    elem_pass=driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
    elem_pass.clear()
    elem_pass.send_keys(user_pass)
    elem_pass.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
def search():
    wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)
    pane=driver.find_element_by_id("userNavigationLabel").click()
open_url("https://www.fb.com")
login("myuserid","mypass")
search()
```

The following error is what i get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to    
locate element: [id="userNavigationLabel"]
```

How should i locate the element?

Comment: You aren't using the `WebDriverWait` correctly. It should look something like `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("userNavigationLabel", By.ID)))`

Comment: I'm sorry, I had that backwards, should be `(By.ID, "userNavigationLabel")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the `WebDriverWait` correctly. It should look something like `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"userNavigationlLabel")))`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to successfully logout from Facebook.

I can see one mistake in your code:

`pane=driver.find_element_by_id("userNavigationLabel").click()` is incorrect.

**Correct Syntax:**

```
pane = driver.find_element_by_id("userNavigationLabel")
pane.click()
```

**You can use lines of code mentioned below for your logout script to work**

```
driver.find_element_by_id("logoutMenu").click()
driver. find_element_by_xpath("//form[contains(@id,'show_me_how_logout')]/../../../..").click()
```